# failing to create a file in flutter

Tags: flutter

i am creating a file as json for storing notes backup

here is the method for creating file,

before i write notes, it showing error in this method to opening a file

```
Future<void> writeNotesToFile() async {
  String path ='/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.noteapp/backup_note.json';
  File? file = File(path);
  print(path);
  bool doesFileExists = await file.exists();

  print(doesFileExists.toString());
  if (doesFileExists==false) {
     file.create();
  }
 
  
}
```

it was working fine...but when i uninstalled the app and installed again..its showing error while calling this method...I have not changed path

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Check Permission: https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

Step 2: Add this plugin to get the directory: https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider

Use below code:

```
final Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final File file = File('${directory.path}/backup_note.json');
await file.create();
```

Comment: Thats okay but i want to know whats wrong after uninstalling...this code was working fine....and one more thing i noticed...its not showing com.example.noteapp folder inside device manager...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add storage permission to store any file in External storage.

For this, you can use the `permission_handler` package.

I am giving an example code of how you can get that permission.

**1. Add the permission_handler package to your pubspec.yaml file:**

```
permission_handler: ^9.0.0
```

**2. Update AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**3. Request the required permissions:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

Future<void> requestStoragePermission() async {
  if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
    // Call your writeNotesToFile() method here.
    writeNotesToFile();
  } else {
    // Permission is not granted.
  }
}
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: I tried all..but not showing request window